# Fullcalendar month view height

Tags: jquery, css, height, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar and in the day and week mode the height is showing correct, but in the month view the the height is half the screen, there is a lot white space below it.

How can i make it so that there is no white space below the month view?

Comment: Please can you create fiddle for this?

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: the following answer is based upon FullCalendar **v2**. If you're using FullCalendar v1, please add a comment and I'll update my answer accordingly.

The `viewRender` method will be triggered when a new date-range is rendered or **when the view type switches**. ([source](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/))

So you could catch the viewRender event, check which view type is currently displayed and adjust the height of FullCalendar when the currently displayed view type is "month".

Example:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    viewRender: function(view, element) {
        if (view.name === "month") {
            $("#calendar").height(500); //change id and height if needed
        } else {
            $("#calendar").height(400); //change id and height if needed
        }
    });
});
```

So you need to add the viewRender property to the options given to FullCalendar on initialization of FullCalendar in your current project.

Comment: In FullCalendar v5, the hook function is now called viewDidMount.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-render-hooks